# OCR Seven Segment Digits Reliably RSA Token

Tags: node.js, ocr, raspberry-pi3

I have been messing around with trying to take an image of an RSA Key Fob and then cropping the image to each digit and eroding it using SSOCR to darken the segments. Through much frustration I have managed to get it to read after controlling many variables like light and movement. However, it does not consistently give me a number and sometimes it will give me a number with 1 or 2 digits off. Is it possible to reliably OCR an RSA key fob and if so are there any examples of it? Any help would be appreciated.

Also I am using `SSOCR` on a raspberry pi with the raspberry pi 2 camera and `raspistill`.

Example Code of taking image and getting the first digit:

```
 var takeImage = function() {

    var exCommand = "raspistill -t 1500 -ISO 50 -q 100 -br 60 --drc off -o " + __dirname + "/stream/img.jpg"
    exec(exCommand, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Error snapping pic -- ");
        }
        ssocrDigits1()
        setTimeout(function() {
            takeImage()
        }, 15000)

    })
}

var ssocrDigits1 = function() {
    var exCommand = "ssocr crop 1240 1025 135 210 white_border 10 erosion remove_isolated -d 1 stream/img.jpg -t 50 -o stream/digits1.png"
    exec(exCommand, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Error ssocring -- ");
        }
        digit1 = stdout.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
        console.log(digit1)
    })
}
```

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with example images from your setup and a description of how they were taken (fixed camera and token or handheld, consistent lighting or random, etc.).

Comment: @Chase I guess my question is more about is it possible and is it sustainable? I have a case I built around the pi and camera with the key fob positioned underneath the camera with LED for back lighting.

Comment: It's clearly possible, the lib author talks about this exact use case on the project's [home page](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/)

Comment: Yeah after much tweaking and building a stable case from legos and then running all number failures through bluematrix for machine learning, we have a 95% success rate.